# How to protect search page on PHP with PDO statement

Tags: php, mysql, security, pdo

I have the simple search page with the code:

```
$keywords = str_replace(' ','%',$_POST['keywords']);
if(isset($_POST['search']) && !empty($keywords)) {
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT ... WHERE `tags` LIKE ? OR `tags` LIKE ? OR `tags` LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute(array("$keywords %", "% $keywords %", "% $keywords"));
foreach($stmt as $row){
  echo ...;
 }
}
```

How to protect this page as more as possible? The question includes: is it right to use mysql_real_escape_string & stripslashes for PDO or there is something else like them?

ps. At the moment I only moved dbconfig up one level and out of the public_html folder using include('../dbconfig.php')

Comment: _“is it right to use mysql_real_escape_string & stripslashes for PDO or there is something else like them?”_ – you have not understood yet what prepared statements _do_. They send the query and the data to the DBMS separately, so no additional escaping of any kind is necessary.

Comment: prepare is enough for protection. Maybe you have to explode keywods and re-concatenate it with `$pdo->quote` if you want to escape the `%` character that could be in `$_POST['keywords']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using prepared statements which is the correct way.  I suggest to sanitize user submitted data previously with **PHP** [filters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php).

```
 $keywords=filter_var($_POST['keywords'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```